# Does this sentence make sense? It feels off: We aim to bring voices to the table otherwise we will not be heard

Tags: grammar

"We aim to bring voices to the table otherwise will not be heard."

I am not sure if it should be:
"We aim to bring voices to the table who otherwise will not be heard".

If it is okay I would prefer to keep the first one. How do you guys feel?

Comment: You need either the "who" you suggest, or "We aim to bring voices to the table, (;) otherwise we will not be heard." The two sentences would have different meanings.

Comment: _Voices to the table_ is a mixed metaphor. People to the table or voices to the discussion/conversation.

Comment: @KarlG actually it's a common idiom, and Google Ngrams suggests it's the *most common* of the three ("voices to the table/discussion/conversation") for AmE, but Ngrams gives a null result for BritE.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with the grammar.  ‘Voices’ is being used either metaphorically (standing for ‘arguments’ or possibly ‘plenty of people’.  The word ‘heard’ is intended to mean “heeded” or ‘taken seriously’

No, the trouble is the sentence falls into an ambiguity which will make it ridiculous.  It carries the comic effect of bathos (anticlimax).

Because, it has the pointless other literal meaning that if we come to the table without our voices (don’t speak), we will not be heard.  Of course not:  we are silent!